# Oracle database 11g configuration assistant failed

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

ORA-27102: out of memory
OSD-00026: additional error information
O/S-Error: (OS 1455) The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
select TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
ORA-27102: out of memory
OSD-00026: additional error information
O/S-Error: (OS 1455) The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
select TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
ORA-27102: out of memory
OSD-00026: additional error information
O/S-Error: (OS 1455) The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
select TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
ORA-27102: out of memory
OSD-00026: additional error information
O/S-Error: (OS 1455) The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
select TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
ORA-27102: out of memory
OSD-00026: additional error information
O/S-Error: (OS 1455) The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
select TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
ORA-27102: out of memory
OSD-00026: additional error information
O/S-Error: (OS 1455) The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
select TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
ORA-27102: out of memory
OSD-00026: additional error information
O/S-Error: (OS 1455) The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
select TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
ORA-27102: out of memory
OSD-00026: additional error information
O/S-Error: (OS 1455) The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
select TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
ORA-27102: out of memory
OSD-00026: additional error information
O/S-Error: (OS 1455) The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
select TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0

Comment: Ok, so you just dump an unformatted mass of error messages, with no question, not context, no explanation of what you were doing that resulted in the messages.  What do you really expect?  Start by googling the error messages, one at a time.  I'll give you a hint .. "ORA-01034: ORACLE not available " means you are not actually connected to a database.

Comment: I tried downloading oracle 11g release 2. When i click "run as administrator" the installation is not starting

Comment: When you click _what_ ?  What was the name of the file you downloaded?  Are you reading the Installation Guide for the version of oracle and the OS on which you are installing?  Why are you even bothering with 11g, which is obsolete and out of support.  Did you follow up by googling the error messages - ORA-ORA-27102, ORA-01034,

Answer (score 0):

The message "The paging file is too small for this operation to complete" suggests you are doing this on Windows.

You need to increase the size of your paging file  "Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advanced Settings"

This would suggest however, that your PC might not be up to the task, but this should at least allow you get a database created and up and running.

You may need to re-run the configuration assistant and choose "Delete" the database you just tried to create, because it might have left some pieces around.  Do that and then try create a new one.